# eex syntax or Phoenix code inside js file

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, gettext

Inside  tag in my index.html.eex i can use this syntax to retrive text.

```
<%= gettext "Login failed!"%>
```

Now i have a js file used for validating fields, and i load this file as a script inside index.html.eex.

Everything works fine but i need to use gettext for Phoenix text translation inside the js file. I know that <%= %> syntax won't compile outside .eex files, however i refuse to put all my validation logic code inside a  in index.html.eex
What can i do to get phoenix code inside a js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the translations in a variable in `index.html.eex` and then access it from the JS files. Here's an example:

Add this to the top of `index.html.eex`:

```
<script>
  var Translations = {
    "login_failed": <%= raw Poison.encode!(gettext("Login failed!")) %>,
  };
</script>
```

Now in your JS file, do:

```
console.log(Translations.login_failed)
```

---

A better way would be to create a list of such translations and inject them in your layout file:

```
<script>
  var Translations = {
    "login_failed": <%= raw Poison.encode!(gettext("Login failed!")) %>,
    "some_other_error": <%= raw Poison.encode!(gettext("Some other error!")) %>,
  };
</script>
```

This way all translations will be available in `app.js`.

---

Why `raw` and `Poison.encode!`?

Simply doing `"<%= thing %>"` or `'<%= thing %>'` will break if `thing` contains quotes or newlines (and probably some other special characters). `Poison.encode!` will convert the value into valid JSON (which is also valid JS) and `raw` will ensure this value is not double escaped.

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert ! Just one more thing: why do i need to call Poison.encode!  on gettext? it works well without it

Comment: Are you sure it works without `Poison.encode!`? `Poison.encode!` will properly escape any special characters in the string and also add double quotes around the value. You could do `"<%= gettext(...) %>"` but that will break if the translation contains e.g. newlines.

Comment: Sure about that. I'm using this syntax and it works like a charm

'<%= gettext "Login failed!" %>'

Comment: Yep adding quotes will work but it'll break if the translation contains quotes or newlines. `Poison.encode!` will convert those characters to valid JS strings.

Comment: Using Poison.encode! return this value
"pswdNotMatch": &quot;Passwords don&#39;t match. Please retry&quot;

And i get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Comment: Ah right. You need to call `raw` as well on that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was trying raw already and solved it :) Thnx anyway, now it works perfectly